# is libc_malloc_debug_leak removed from Android Noughat? Is there any replacement for the same?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

My app uses `libc_malloc_debug_leak.so`. Upto Android M, it is working fine. But with Android N it is failing with message saying

> libc_malloc_debug_leak.so not found

To confirm this I checked the `/system/lib/` folder in my Android N machine. I haven't found the same. So Is there any specific reason google removed this from source and what is replacement for this?